# Нужно ли тире перед "это"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли в следующем предложении тире (или запятая и тире) перед "это"?

Однако в тех случаях, когда при холодной опрессовке технологической установки утечек нет, но они появляются в «горячем режиме», это может указывать на низкое качество монтажного проектирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь " это" не является связкой, поэтому тире не нужно.